# Calculation of AICc NonLinearModelFit

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I have been using `NonlinearModelFit` in a current study. Outputs from this procedure include AIC and AICc.

AICc can be calculated from AIC via the following relation:

$$\text{AICc} = \text{AIC} + \frac{2k(k+1)}{n-k-1}$$

If a model with $3$ parameters is considered, then $k = 3$, and if $5$ data points are used in the fitting then $n = 5$. With these assumptions,

$$\frac{2k(k+1)}{n-k-1}=\frac{2\times 3(3+1)}{5-3-1}=24/1=24$$

The denominator of this expression would be zero for $4$ data points.

I have performed an analysis with 5 data points. The value of AICc should be AIC + 24.  In this instance `NonlinearModelFit` calculated AICc = `Infinity`.

Is this an error or am I missing something?

Comment: Estimating 3 parameters (and probably 4 parameters if one counts the error variance) with just 5 data points and expecting a good enough result (coefficient estimates and/or AIC) is...well...just plain silly.

Comment: Jim, I know that you are indeed right.  The bigger question is:

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 7):

You're not counting all of the parameters as you need to include the error variance.  So with $n=5$ data points and 3 coefficients and one error variance the number of parameters is $k=4$ and $n-k-1=0$, hence the resulting infinity.  (Variances are parameters, too!)

See [Hurvich & Tsai (1989)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biomet/76.2.297) (*Biometrika* (1989), **76**, 2, pp. 297-307).

**Update**

So for a standard regression model with just a single error term *Mathematica* uses the Hurvich & Tsai (1989) formula:

$$AIC_c=AIC+{{2(k+1)(k+2)}\over{n-k-2}}$$

where $k$ is the number of parameters in the model (not counting the error variance).  (For a linear model $k$ is the rank of the design matrix.)  This gives $\infty$ when $k=n-2$ as you found.

For whatever it's worth `PROC MIXED` in SAS with `METHOD=ML` (`ML` for maximum likelihood rather than `REML` for restricted maximum likelihood) with a single error variance uses a slightly different formula for $AIC_c$ to avoid dividing by zero when $k=n-2$:

$$AIC_c=AIC+{{2(k+1)(k+2)}\over{\max{(n,k+3)}-k-2}}$$

Comment: Thanks Jim.  You put me on the right track